# HP VAR's Value Added Reseller, Datacenter Enterprise Servers

Tags: hp

Greetings Team,

I am looking for a list of HP VAR's (Value Added Resellers), both domestic and international.

Primary goal is to speak with these people and build a relationship to purchase brand new enterprise class level of HP server side equipment.

Interested in 1U and 2U rackmount servers based on Intel Nehalem processors.

Quantity of purchasing is depending on our many clients needs, as a Hosting provider
I will be looking looking to place orders or my clients place orders.
Some weeks may only be a dozen while others can be a hundered.

If anyone out there works with HP resellers if you can send me a link to their reseller  websites or if the information is private and not to be shared send me an email noneil@logicworks.net

If this is a bit to off track for the subjects on this discussion group or violates any terms of the discussions within this for my apologies i withdraw the request.

Have a great day all.
Best,
Nick

Answer (score 2):

You might also check HP's own list for "Find a Reseller" - http://h20465.www2.hp.com/GPL/search.aspx?language_code=en&country_code=us&SearchType=SMB

Personally, I do not like doing business with VARs when I can deal with the company directly.

Comment: +1 When purchasing in the quantity he described, I'd just deal directly with HP. They'll be very friendly with sales like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had excellent service from [Dasher Technologies](http://www.dashertechnologies.com/).  Their nominal customer size is the small to medium business, but we were ordering hundreds of systems at a time from them and getting excellent quality and fast response out of them.  I would certainly work with them again given the chance.  Chris Stewart was the rep we dealt with.  I would start with him and go from there.

Comment: Thank you so much Travis, I will reach out to Dasher Technologies.  Have a great day.